# Sum of all values in the corresponding cell, against a particular calendar month and Company

Tags: excel, excel-formula

An excel sheet contains an array of repeating **"calendar months"** in Column-1, an array of repeating **"Company Names"** in Column-2, and an array of **Numerical Values** in Column-3.

> *(1) What is the sum of all values in Column-3 for any random company for any random month?*
>   *(2) what is the sum of all values in Column-3 for any random company **up to its previous month?***

However, I found the solution for Question (1), but unable to find the solution for Question (2). Thank you very for your help in Advance!
I have uploaded the file.

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/31e85g5j0njsxr8/Solve.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Many of us won't be able to open this file , You should post your input and desired output screenshot in your question.

Comment: Hi Imran, try opening now. Thank you.

Comment: (1) [homework] questions **must** show what you've attempted. (2) If you used a SUMIF for the first part, use a SUMIFS for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off my previous answer, give this a shot.

[Worksheet here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak6r9nlUd1ZOjPErgLlFyDzsohqNzg)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very very much Jeranon. You have solved the problem! great!! hatsoff!!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how your data looks like I'm giving general solution.

It looks to me that you can use a simple sumifs formula for your described problem.

> =SUMIFS(D1:D10,C1:C10,"<"&DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),B1:B10,"="&A2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my answer to your last question, you can just add other conditions to the `SUMPRODUCT` like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(DATEVALUE("01"&A2:A55&"2018"))<MONTH(DATEVALUE("01"&$B$1&"2018")))*(C2:C55)*(B2:B55="XYZ"))
```

**Array Formula: press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**